# CSS Radial Gradient Styling

Tags: css, vue.js, gradient, banner, radial-gradients

I am trying to build banner with background that has radial gradient. I think I am close but cannot make my code exactly as design. Any help would be highly appreciated. I am not able to get proper colour and  display only portion of first circle.

This the design I am trying to build
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjrfW.png)

and below is my code pen.

https://codepen.io/aneelk/pen/JjaeNqO

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
     <div class= "header3">
       <div class = "header-circles"></div>
         <p class="welcome-to-your-dash2">Welcome to your dashboard</p>
         <p class="left-text2">SCHOOL SMART GOALS : <span class='color-green'> 183 </span> SET  <span class='color-green'> 96</span> ARCHEIVED</p> 
  </div>    
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {  
  },
  methods: {
    
  }
};
</script>

<!-- Use preprocessors via the lang attribute! e.g. <style lang="scss"> -->
<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

  .color-green{
  height: 24px;
  width: 61px;
  color: #37B729;
  font-family: ".SF NS Display";
  font-size: 21px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 24px;
  }
  
     .header3 {
    height : 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:  #032D36;
    overflow:hidden;
             position: relative;

  }
     .welcome-to-your-dash2 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;       
       z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;

  }
  .left-text2 {
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-family: ".SF NS Display";
   font-size: 12px;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   margin-top: 10%;
   margin-right: 10%; 
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 5;
   right: 0;
  }  
  .header-circles {
   width:100%;
   height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at -25% 50%,#fff 0%, #0D414D 0%, #0C5D70 0.1%, transparent),radial-gradient(circle at 60% 10%, #0C5D70 20%, #0D414D 5%, transparent), radial-gradient(circle at 10% 10%, #0C5D70 9%, #0D414D 1%, transparent) ;
     opacity:50%;
      position: absolute;
     z-index: 0;

  }
</style>
```

I am new to CSS gradient and currently learning. I am seeking help so that I can design better. I have added both my problem and current attempt in description above.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOtfJ.png)

Comment: I am happy to help, but I can't see exactly what isn't right, because the colours and gradients are all very dark, similar and subtle. Can you perhaps explain in more detail what you are getting versus what you expect? Perhaps with some side-by-side screenshots? Or perhaps you can create an example using brighter colours which will better illustrate the issue?

Comment: Hi  @BrettDonald Thank you for you response. I am trying get the same colour in my gradients as in the sample . I want it to look brighter and fade on the side for the small circle.  I have updated my post to include screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Based on your most recent comment, I made a simplified version of your UI with just a single circle, that has a brighter/glowing center, just to make everything easier to read and understand.  Basically this code says "draw a circle with its center at `x=10%, y=10%`.  The center of the circle should be `#4C9DB0`.  At 9% of the circle's width, it should be `#0C5D70`, and then we should swap to transparent and stay there for the remainder of the circle".  The [documentation on radial gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient) has more details on the formatting and different use cases.

The smooth transition from `#4C9DB0` to `#0C5D70` in the center of the circle is what produces the "glow" effect.  `#4C9DB0` is not any special number, I just shifted your provided color towards white; you can feel free to adjust as necessary.

```css
.header-circles {
   width:100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 10% 10%, #4C9DB0, #0C5D70 9%, transparent 9%) ;
   opacity:50%;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 0;
  }
  
  .header3 {
    height : 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:  #032D36;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
  }
```

```html
<div class="header3">

  <div class="header-circles">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, how can  I get the circle to be dimmer on one side one (so that half of it looks faded)?